# Reading data from the socket doesn't work

Tags: multithreading, sockets

I have a server and a client. My server writes to the client through the socket two times, one after the other, both being successful. The client reads the data from the server's first read, but it blocks on the second read, as no data was sent.

What can be the problem?

Can this be because the write call from the server is called before the read from the client?

Comment: We don't really have enough information to help you solve the problem. Could you post the code for the client and server?

Answer (score 1):

This is simply the nature of TCP.  It is a streaming protocol, there is no 1-to-1 relationship between sends and reads.  The only guarantee is that what is sent is what is received, in the same order it is sent.

A write must send at least 1 byte, and at most the number of bytes specified, or anywhere in between, so it may take multiple writes to completely send a given piece of data. The network can packetize those writes however it wants to optimize transmissions (unless you configure the socket otherwise).

A read must return at least 1 byte, and at most the number of bytes specified, or anywhere in between, so it may take multiple reads to completely receive a given piece of data, regardless of how many writes it took to send.

TCP has no concept of message boundaries, so you have to explicitly frame the data you send in such a way that the receiver knows where one message ends and the next begins.  Either:

- send the data length before sending the actual data. The receiver can then read the length, and then read however many bytes the length specifies.
- send a unique delimiter at the end of the data, which is guaranteed not to appear in the data itself. The receiver can then read until it encounters the delimiter.